# is there a way to have two mappedBy="something"?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to **Spring** and **JPA**. i have a parent `class` called `parent` with attribute 
        `@OneToMany(mappedBy="father")
        private List<Student> children = new ArrayList<>();`

and another `class Student` with the attributes

```
      @ManyToOne
      private Parent father;

      @ManyToOne
      private Parent mother;
```

When i want to delete a father it works , but not the mother .

I do want to keep the two attributes `father` and `mother` and have them both mapped to `childen`

**Any suggestions please ?? thanks**

Comment: it kind of yes , but i do wanna keep both attributes father and mother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define two lists of children, one for father and one for mother, being a bidirectional relationship

Change:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="father")
private List<Student> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

To:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="mother")
private List<Student> childrenMother = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="father")
private List<Student> childrenFather = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I've actually did this at the end , but i although think it's not really a good conception (it's not the best solution ), don't u think so !

Comment: I look forward to any other solution!